# How to mock Django REST framework RawQuery?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, mocking

I'm developing BBS API with Django REST framework. I tried to mock RawQuery because Django test database doesn't work, but my mock code also doesn't work.

models.py

```
from django.db import models                                                                                                                                                              
# Converts snake_case to camelCase here because clients use camelCase.

class Board(models.Model):
  boardID: models.IntegerField = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name: models.CharField = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  path: models.CharField = models.CharField(max_length=64)

  @staticmethod
  def get(lang):
    q = '''
        SELECT board_id AS boardID, name, path FROM bbs.boards
          WHERE language = %s
          ORDER BY order_in_lang
        '''
    return Board.objects.raw(q, [lang])
```

serializers.py

```
from bbs_api.bbs_api import models                                                                                                                                                from rest_framework import serializers


class BoardSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = models.Board
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from bbs_api.bbs_api import models, serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response


class EnBoardsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

  def get(self, request):
    raw_query_set = models.Board.get('en')
    boards_serializer = serializers.BoardSerializer(raw_query_set, many=True)
    return Response(boards_serializer.data)
```

tests.py

```
from django.db.models.query import RawQuerySet
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.test import TestCase
from bbs_api.bbs_api import models, serializers, views
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.serializers import BaseSerializer, ListSerializer
from rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers import ReturnList
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
import traceback


class EnBoardsViewSetTest(TestCase):

  @patch('rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.data')
  def test_get_returns_en_boards(self, mocked_data):
    expected = [
      {'lang': 'en', 'name': 'News', 'path': '/boards/en/news',
       'minutes_to_live': 1440, 'order_in_lang': 1},
      {'lang': 'en', 'name': 'Politics', 'path': '/boards/en/politics',
       'minutes_to_live': 1440, 'order_in_lang': 2},
    ]

    mocked_data = PropertyMock(return_value=expected)

    req = Request(HttpRequest())
    view_set = views.EnBoardsViewSet()
    res = view_set.get(req)

    result = res.data

    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

I tried to mock `rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.data` because it looks like this property finally executes a raw query.
I run `./mange.py test` and get

```
Found 1 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_get_returns_en_boards (bbs_api.bbs_api.tests.EnBoardsViewSetTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1379, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "/home/admin01/project/bbs/bbs_api/bbs_api/bbs_api/tests.py", line 31, in test_get_returns_en_boards
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
AssertionError: [] != [{'lang': 'en', 'name': 'News', 'path': '/[169 chars]: 2}]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

### Environment

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Python 3.10.12
- Django 4.2.1
- djangorestframework 3.14.0